# How to use 'safe-json-stringify' in Angular 4 Application?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, stringify

My requirement is to convert JSON object to string. For this, simply JSON.stringify() doesn't work here because it contains circular references. I searched on the internet then I found a package which does this work for me. But in the usage of the package it is mentioned like `const safeJsonStringify = require('safe-json-stringify');`. But here the problem is that in Angualar 4 doesn't support `require()` function anymore. In latest versions of Angular (from version 2), we have `import` statements. It is like if we have a class is exported in the package then we can directly import that class from the package.

Any suggestions ??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: u can use require by installing @types/node and including it in tsconfig.json

Comment: @hana_wujira, Thanks for your answers. Could you tell me how to install require()? and include it in the tsconfig.json?

Comment: if u are using npm to install - npm install @types/node

Comment: @hana_wujira, I don't whether it will work or not. But I got the answer. See the below accepted answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import * as SafeJsonStringify from 'safe-json-stringify'
```

This way your `import statement` can act (in some ways) as a typical `require()`, as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import#Import_an_entire_module's_contents).

Note:  `SafeJsonStrinfigy` is a value of your choice: you can name it as you like.

Comment: Thanks so much !!. you are fantastic !!. It's working for me.